# How can I sync between multiple threads so that their transaction ID be unique without using mutex?

Tags: c, multithreading

I'm writing an application in C that requires multiple threads to request a unique transaction ID from a function as shown below;

```
struct list{
  int id;
  struct list *next
};

function generate_id()
{
  linked-list is built here to hold 10 millions 
}
```

How can I sync between two or more threads so that their transaction ID be unique among them without using mutex, is it possible?

Please share anything even if I need to change linked list to something else.

Comment: To me it's not clear how the generation of the transaction id is related to the linked list. The knowledge of how the ID is generated is IMO required for an appropriate answer.

Answer (score 0):

Let me first guess what you are trying to do(correct me if I am wrong):

Call the function "generate_id" from each thread and manipulate a global counter to assign unique ids to each linked-list node.

In doing so, you obviously need to have mutual exclusion. In addition to mutex, it can be also achieved by using atomic operations like "test-and-test-and-set" or "compare-and-swap".